# ubuntu on WSL inside corporate firewall

Tags: upgrade, windows-subsystem-for-linux

New to ubuntu, new to WSL, I'm not even able to get ping to work.  I've just installed ubuntu and it seems to be running fine. I've set proxy using

```
export http_proxy=http://mycompany.net:8080
```

Apt-get-upgrade seemed to work but with "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."  Ping just locks up.

Also, as recommended, tried

```
sudo apt-get --print-uris install PROGRAM
```

which resulted in 'E: Unable to locate package PROGRAM'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping will not work without a route direct to the internet. That you have to indicates that you do not have such a route, but rather have to go trough a proxy. This is common in corporate environments.

As you get no error messages when you run `apt update`, this indicates that everything is fine.

Comment: I had http_proxy set but not https_proxy

Comment: The [edit of the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1022324/revisions) kind of invalidates my answer. As it is now more or less a duplicate, I will not update the answer.